# prove $\inf S = -\sup (-S)$

Tags: analysis

Let $-S$ be the set $\left\{ -s:s \in S \right\}$ where $-S$ is the set that contains negatives of the members of $S$. We want to prove that $\inf(S) = -\sup(-S)$

Here is how I proved it
Let $s_0= \sup(-S)$. That is for all $-s_1\in -S$ then $-s_1 \leq s_0$. Multiplying both sides by $-1$ we get $-s_0 \leq s_1$ for all $s_1 \in S$. So $\inf(S)=-s_0=-\sup(-S)$ It looks short and sweet. Not sure if its right though.

Comment: Looks like Brian M. Scott posted a few seconds ahead of me because I spent some time editing the question.  Where I found $sup(-S)$ and $inf(-S)$ I wrote $\sup(-S)$ and $\inf(-S)$, coded as \sup(-S) and \inf(-S), with a backslash.  This (1) prevents italicization, (2) provides proper spacing in experssions like $a\sup b$, which would otherwise look like $a sup b$, and (3) in "displayed" contexts, affects positions of subscripts in things like $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in A}f(x)$.

Comment: OK thanks. Looks like ill need to go back and figure it out. I just thought of it right now.

Comment: Could I just add in there that $\inf(S)=-s_0$ since $-s_0 \leq s_1$ for all $s_1 \in S$.

Answer (score 6):

It’s fine as far as it goes, but it’s incomplete. You’ve shown that $-\sup(-S)$ is **a** lower bound for $S$, but not that it’s the **greatest** lower bound. If you assume that it’s not the greatest lower bound, you can use the same basic idea to get a contradiction; I’ll leave it to you to try that on your own, but I’ll be happy to say more if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This argument is incomplete.  If $s_0=\sup(-S)$, the certainly for all $s_1\in S$ we have $-s_1\le s_0$.  But that says only that $s_0$ is an upper bound of $-S$, not that is is the *least* upper bound.  You have to account for "leastness".